# Local pyspark cannot import

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to run Spark locally using pyspark but I keep getting the following error when I try to import pyspark.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pyspark
  File "C:\SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "C:\SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\python\pyspark\context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "C:\SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "C:\SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pyspark import cloudpickle
  File "C:\SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: code expected at least 16 arguments, got 15
```

This is my Python code:

```py
# Find Spark location
import findspark
findspark.init("C:/SPARK/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8")

# Imports
import pyspark

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="SparkTest")
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I'm using Windows 10 64-bit and Python 3.11.